# Returning an array of values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to get a list of values from a set of element attributes and store them in an array.

Currently, I am doing this:

```
var ids = [];

$("my selector").each(function (idx, v) {

    ids.push($(v).data("id"));
});
```

This seems a bit clunky. Is there a more efficient/streamlined way of doing this? Perhaps something more like this:

```
var ids = $("my selector").data("id");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) along with [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) in this context,

```
var ids = $("my selector").map(function(){
   return $(this).data("id");
}).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Less clunky:

```
$("my selector").each(function () {
    ids.push($(this).data("id"));
});
```

By, removing `idx` and `v`, you can use `$(this)`